# Is a photoelectric encoder affected by small high frequency vibrations?

Tags: arduino, voltage, power, current, programming

Referring to [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHtNs.png), I have bought the same photoelectric rotary encoder.

In the picture below, I have attached a microbrushless DC motor to the rotary encoder to control using PID in Arduino.
When I tried to write a simple program to run both encoders together with a fixed PWM to be fed into the microbrushless DC motor and without PID, the encoder keeps skipping steps.

I am certain that the encoder cannot handle small high frequency vibrations from the microbrushless DC motor because when I disconnect the DC motor and tried to rotate it by my hand, it works perfectly fine.  I have also give it a recommended voltage of 5-12V DC using a lithium ion battery.

Is this photoelectric rotary encoder not able to handle small high frequency vibrations? Is there any other encoder recommendation that is not so susceptible to vibration noise?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Working Arduino Code

```
/* 

  Read a rotary encoder using interupts
  Encoder common <-> ground
  ENCODER0_PINA <-> pin 2
  ENCODER0_PINB <-> pin 4

*/

#define ENCODER0_PINA 2
#define ENCODER0_PINB 4

volatile int ENCODER0_pos = 0;


void setup() {
  
  pinMode(ENCODER0_PINA, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(ENCODER0_PINA, HIGH);     // Turn on pullup resistor
  pinMode(ENCODER0_PINB, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(ENCODER0_PINB, HIGH);     // Turn on pullup resistor
  
  attachInterrupt(0, doEncoder, CHANGE);  // Encoder pin on interrupt 0 (pin 2)

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("start");
  
}

void loop() {

   Serial.println (ENCODER0_pos,DEC); 
   delay(100);
  
}

void doEncoder() {  
  if (digitalRead(ENCODER0_PINA) == digitalRead(ENCODER0_PINB)) {
    ENCODER0_pos ++;
  } else {
    ENCODER0_pos --;
  }
   
}
```

Comment: Are you using the position or taking the differential of the position?

Comment: @VoltageSpike, position only :)

Comment: @VoltageSpike, hi, I have found one encoder code  at https://github.com/buxtronix/arduino/tree/master/libraries/Rotary which it says help to prevent vibration and electrical noise at high speed and I believe that's my solution. However, I got this weird error called 'class Rotary' has no member named 'process' and I am stuck at this weird line haha. When you try to download the zip file and extracted it and compile it in Arduino IDE, it would give this weird error :)

Comment: What is the purpose of this setup? What code are you using to read the encoder?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, hi Bruce, the code can be found at github.com/buxtronix/arduino/tree/master/libraries/Rotary which specifically just an encoder code and nothing else, but I encountered some bug when I am trying to compile the code in Arduino :)

Comment: There's at least a 50% chance that your code isn't able to keep up with the encoder. I'd put money on the code not being nimble enough.

Comment: @Andyaka, I am glad that you stop by :) . A lot of highly efficient code is posted at https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/RotaryEncoders/ , and all of them I tried to run using arduino but still the encoder keep skipping steps when undergo mini vibrations from the mini microbrushless motor. If anyone has this encoder at home (mine is 600 steps/rev) , you can try to attach a low power microbrushless motor there and the encoder readings will jump up and down and will skip steps :( . Not sure what can I do to resolve it :)

Comment: Mine one after a 10seconds, can accumulate a 200 steps skipped from a 600 steps/rev encoder :( , very disapointing after 2 days fixing this

Comment: I often used a dedicated decoder chip like LS7366R for high resolution encoders. It can handle vibration artefacts without problems. Some microcontrollers contain a similar qdec hardware.

Comment: @Jens, hi, have you experienced the same problem of skipping steps without using the dedicated decoder chip ? And then after using the decoder chip, it works perfectly well? :). This step-skipping is especially happened when encoder experience little high frequency vibrations, right?

Comment: _"I encountered some bug when I am trying to compile the code in Arduino :)"_ - so this is not the code you are using? Exactly which 'mini microbrushless' motor do you have, and what rpm does it do with the prop on?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, hi,  I have updated all my connections in my post, I have tried the code that is from the video and other efficient code from https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/RotaryEncoders/ . This time I try to REALLY filter out the problem, I disconnect the entire motor and just left a very light straw attached to encoder shaft. However, when I use my hand to slightly rotate the stick violently a bit, the reading skips a lot. I am really not sure what to do anymore as I have been on this problem 24/7 for 3 consective days. I really really really feel like giving up.

Comment: And please, if anyone has this encoder at home, attach a straw like me in the picture and slightly rotate the straw violently, you will see the readings very weird and skip steps. Can anyone just try this if you all have this photoelectric encoder at home?

Comment: You guys should just do this, and you will know what I have experienced

Comment: Seriously, I feel like giving upppppppppppppppp. The encoder is 5V to 12V recommended voltage and I applied a good low impendence 8V using lithium ion already. I really tried so hard on this and yet failedd.

Comment: @Andyaka, hi Mr Andy, may I ask if you have used this photoelectric rotary encoder before?

Comment: No @jessicasmith I've never used it.

Comment: Hi people, I managed to solve it, Serial.println is causing it to lag. Code problem seriously. My God, @Andyaka, your bet was right haha :). Thank God after 3 days of solving that stupid thing

Comment: Updated the Working code, just connect 2 of the 10k resistors to Arduino Pin 2 and 4 and copy the code, it will work fine :). Hope this help anyone who struggles with it

Comment: What encoder make/model is that (not going to watch a video link to figure it out)? Do you know what type of output it has? The hardware is pulling the MCU pins high to battery voltage which is out of safe limits for the MCU pins. On the other hand the resistors are only 10k so it offers protection from immediate damage, but it is still wrong. On the other hand, your code is triggering on pin change, and 10k resistor may provide too slow edge which may cause multiple triggers. You also don't know of the encoder output is filtered or not, so you may get extra edges and count pulses wrong.

Comment: _"Hi people, I managed to solve it, Serial.println is causing it to lag"_ - this is exactly what I suspected was the problem. You can answer your own question with this info.

Comment: @jessicasmith The code you use may fail if the pin status changes between the two calls of "digitalRead()". This may occur on vibrations. if you decode manual rotary switches this may be acceptable, but you cannot trust this method in motor controls. You can inprove this code if you take a port snapshot using a single byte read operation and decode the status later in the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is from a comment by Jessica. I'll delete this if Jessica puts it an answer

- I managed to solve it.
  Serial.println is causing it to lag.

---

Major lesson:

NEVER include a serial output function in a time critical loop without having determined whether the effect on timing is acceptable.

This is a very common problem - many decades old.
If you MUST have a serial routine and it cannot be accommodated using standard print functions you can write / use real time routines - either interrupt or timer driven so that the loop code spends very little time servicing the serial output.